# Cannot reproduce forecast.ets prediction interval for an AAN model

Tags: time-series

In the book *Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing* by Rob J. Hyndman it is said that the analytic formula for the forecast variance for the step h in a AAN model is $v_{n+h | n} = \sigma^2$ for $h = 1$ and $v_{n+h | n} = \sigma^2(1+\sum_{j = 1}^{h-1} c_j^2)$ for $h \geq 2$, where $c_j = \alpha + \beta j$.

The forecast mean is $\mu_{n+h | n} = l_n + h b_n$.

I wrote a code to reproduce the results given by the `forecast( )` function for $1 \leq h \leq 6$. The code is:

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols('^GSPC', from = "2010-01-01", to = "2016-10-01", adjusted = TRUE)

datos1 <- to.monthly(GSPC)
serie1 <- ts(Cl(datos1), frequency = 12, start = c(2010, 01))

#Initial parameters
alpha <- 0.5
beta <- 0.4
l_0 <- 1087.9488
b_0 <- 34.6055 
l_t <- c(l_0)
b_t <- c(b_0)

#Create vector x_t
for( i in seq(1, length(serie1))){
  if(i == 1){
    l_t = c(l_t, alpha*serie1[i]+(1-alpha)*(l_0 + b_0))
    b_t = c(b_t, (beta/alpha)*(l_t[2]-l_0) + (1-(beta/alpha))*b_0) 
  }
  else{
  l_t = c(l_t, alpha*serie1[i]+(1-alpha)*(l_t[i]+b_t[i]))
  b_t = c(b_t, (beta/alpha)*(l_t[i+1]-l_t[i]) + (1-(beta/alpha))*b_t[i])
  }
}

serie2 <- serie1
l1_t <- l_t
b1_t <- b_t

for(i in seq(length(serie1)+1, length(serie1) + 6)){
  serie2 = c(serie2, l1_t[i] + b1_t[i])
  l1_t = c(l1_t, alpha*serie2[i]+(1-alpha)*(l1_t[i]+b1_t[i]))
  b1_t = c(b1_t, (beta/alpha)*(l1_t[i+1]-l1_t[i]) + (1-(beta/alpha))*b1_t[i])
}

#Fitted values

fitted <- c()

for(i in seq(1, length(serie1))){
  if(i == 1){
    fitted = c(fitted, l_0 + b_0)
  }
  else{
    fitted = c(fitted, l_t[i] + b_t[i])
  }
}  

fitted <- ts(fitted, frequency = 12, start = c(2010, 01))
prediction <- ts(tail(serie2, 6), frequency = 12, start = c(2016, 10))

#Estimate σ

residuals <- rep(0, length(serie1))

for(i in seq(1, length(serie1))){
  residuals[i] = serie1[i]-fitted[i]
}

sigma2 <- mean(residuals^2)

#Prediction interval

lower <- c()
upper <- c()
c_j <- alpha+beta*seq(1,5)
v <- 0

for (i in seq(1, 6)){
  if(i == 1){lower = c(lower, 
              qnorm(0.025, mean = l_t[length(l_t)] + i*b_t[length(b_t)], 
              sd = sqrt(sigma2)))
  upper = c(upper, 
            qnorm(0.975, mean = l_t[length(l_t)] + i*b_t[length(b_t)], 
                  sd = sqrt(sigma2)))
  }
  else{

  v = sigma2*(1 + sum(c_j[1:i-1]^2))  

  lower = c(lower, 
            qnorm(0.025, mean = l_t[length(l_t)] + i*b_t[length(b_t)], 
                  sd = sqrt(v)))
  upper = c(upper, 
            qnorm(0.975, mean = l_t[length(l_t)] + i*b_t[length(b_t)], 
                  sd = sqrt(v)))
  }
}

forecast_analytic1 <- cbind(prediction, lower, upper)
colnames(forecast_analytic1) <- c('Forecast', 'Lower', 'Upper')

library(expsmooth)

modelo <- ets(serie1, model = "AAN", alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.4, gamma = NULL, damped = FALSE)

pred_analytic <- forecast(modelo, h = 6, level = 95)
```

For $h = 1$ it got the same result of the `forecast( )` function, but for $h \geq 2$ it differs. Could anyone tell me what the mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a new bug, unfortunately. Now fixed on the github version. The following code shows the equivalences

```
> library(forecast)
> fit <- ets(WWWusage, model="AAN", damped=FALSE)
> 
> #Model parameters
> alpha <- coef(fit)['alpha']
> beta <- coef(fit)['beta']
> n <- length(WWWusage)
> l_0 <- fit$states[n+1,'l']
> b_0 <- fit$states[n+1,'b']
> 
> # Using forecast function
> forecast(fit, level=95, h=6)
    Point Forecast    Lo 95    Hi 95
101       217.9994 210.9313 225.0675
102       215.9990 200.1956 231.8024
103       213.9986 187.5548 240.4424
104       211.9982 173.2885 250.7079
105       209.9978 157.5847 262.4109
106       207.9974 140.5790 275.4158
> 
> # Using equation in Table 6.3 of the book
> h <- seq(6)
> v <- fit$sigma2 * (1 + (h-1)*(alpha^2 + alpha*beta*h + (1/6)*beta^2*h*(2*h-1)))
> mu <- l_0 + b_0*h
> cbind(Forecast=mu, 
+       Lower=qnorm(0.025, mean=mu, sd=sqrt(v)),
+       Upper=qnorm(0.975, mean=mu, sd=sqrt(v)))
     Forecast    Lower    Upper
[1,] 217.9994 210.9313 225.0675
[2,] 215.9990 200.1956 231.8024
[3,] 213.9986 187.5547 240.4424
[4,] 211.9982 173.2885 250.7079
[5,] 209.9978 157.5847 262.4109
[6,] 207.9974 140.5790 275.4158
> 
> # Using equation (6.1) from the book
> cj <- alpha + beta*seq(5)
> v <- fit$sigma2 * cumsum(c(1,cj^2))
> cbind(Forecast=mu, 
+       Lower=qnorm(0.025, mean=mu, sd=sqrt(v)),
+       Upper=qnorm(0.975, mean=mu, sd=sqrt(v)))
     Forecast    Lower    Upper
[1,] 217.9994 210.9313 225.0675
[2,] 215.9990 200.1956 231.8024
[3,] 213.9986 187.5547 240.4424
[4,] 211.9982 173.2885 250.7079
[5,] 209.9978 157.5847 262.4109
[6,] 207.9974 140.5790 275.4158
```